# Sample Space Partitioning

Tags: probability

A box contains $ n $ balls, $ r $ balls of which are of same specific color.
Two players each will draw one ball at a time and put it back. This repeats until some player draws a ball of the same-specific-color balls, then he is the winner.

Let $ A $ be the event the first player wins, and $ B $ the event the second player wins.

Do $ A $ and $ B $ partition the sample space? Why?

What about $ A $ and $ \bar{A} $?

To calculate $ P(A) $ and $ P(B) $:

Let $ P(A) = x $. From total probability we have $ P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) $, and since $ P(B|A) = 0 $, $ P(B) = P(B|\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) = \frac{r}{n} (1 - x) $

Are these steps correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at.  In theory, this game might never stop.  The players might never draw the winning color.  Probability $0$ (assuming $r>0$) but it is still a possible scenario.

Comment: There are two natural choices for the sample space here which give opposite answers to your question. Either the same space consists of all infinite sequences of draws, or all finite ones ending in one of the $r$ special balls.

Comment: "Not sure what you are getting at." Answer? To my question?? :)

Comment: First question: no, see lulu's comment (an infinite sequence of all non-winning draws is in neither event). Second question: Yes, by definition of complement of an event.

Comment: Then $ A $, $ B $, and the event that no one winning $ \bar{A} \cap \bar{B} $ form partition?

Comment: Based on your answer, $ P(A) + P(B) = 1 $ is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a terminating game...

Event $A_1$: A wins at the first round. $p(A_1)= a =\frac{r}n$

Now, due to symmetry: if $A$ doesn't win in the first round, the probability of $B$ winning is equal to $A$ winning

$$p(B) = (1-a)p(A)$$

and since complementary events

$$p(A) = 1 - p(B)$$

substituting in gives

$$ p(A) = \frac{1}{2-a} \\
p(B) = \frac{1-a}{2-a}
$$

Comment: Then I should have written $ P(B) = P(B|\bar{A}_1) P(\bar{A}_1) = \frac{n - r}{n} x $

Comment: What do you mean exactly by symmetry? What if there are more than two players?

Comment: Symmetry in the sense that if the first player doesn't win in the first round, you can think the game starts fresh for the second player now playing first.

Comment: Also, note that if $r=0=a$, the game will never end, but we set the probabilities equal.  This will be the degenerate case with a good default value.

Comment: You can extend to multi players but the computations will be more cumbersome.